# What is wrong with my function that it keeps throwing the not a function error?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting the error

> `slides.addEventListener` is not a function.

How come?

Here is the code:

```
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.home__slide');

slides.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
});
```

Comment: Because whatever "slides" is doesn't have an "addEventListener" function?

Comment: You're essentially asking the wrong question.  You're getting that error because, well, `slides.addEventListener` is not a function.  The question you *should* be asking to yourself first is why exactly do you think it *should be* a function?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a HTMLCollection. You need to iterate through individual nodes in the collection to attach the event listener.

Comment: I might have just looked at the docs for "querySelectorAll", or searched for "querySelectorAll addEventListener".

Comment: Use document.querySelector, or add an index like this: slides[0].addEventListener.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, not a single item, so it doesn't have an `.addEventListener`. You can isntead use `slides.forEach(slice => slide.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => { clearInterval(slideInterval); });` to add an even listener to each, or if there is a single element you expect, then just use `const slides = document.querySelector('.home__slide');`